# Carga de datos a través de un servidor

Tags: c#, windows-forms

estoy intentando cargar distintos tipos de datos para un formulario. La carga de los datos tiene que hacerse antes de la visualización del formulario, ya que uno de esos datos que quiero cargar hace depender el funcionamiento y el diseño del formulario entero, la cosa es que no se como hacer para que cargue esos datos antes de ejecutar `InitializeComponent()` o cualquier otro método. He seguido paso a paso la ejecución, pero en cierto punto pega un salto en el código y carga lo que no quiero. Os paso mas o menos lo que tengo.

Constuctor del formulario:

```
    public FormAreaPersonal()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, true);
        InitializeComponent();
        DoubleBuffered = true;
    }
```

Código que quiero que ejecute antes de que se visualice el formulario: (Puede no estar bien el código pero es lo que he intentado)

```
        sacarCurso();
        if (usuario.Equals("invitado") || curso == 0)
        {
            cargarModelo();
        }
        else
        {
            sacarUsuario();
            sacarAsignaturas();
            cargaComponentes();
            cargaGraficas(curso);
        }
```

Lo que hacen esos métodos es:

```
   public async void sacarCurso()
    {
        Task<int> cursoTask = met.sacarCurso(usuario);
        curso = await cursoTask;

    }
    public async void sacarUsuario()
    {
        Task<int> userTask = met.sacarUsuario(usuario);
        user = await userTask;
    }
    public async void sacarAsignaturas()
    {
        Task<List<string>> asignaturasTask = met.sacarAsignaturas(curso, usuario);
        nombresAsignaturas = await asignaturasTask;
    }
```

Gracias.

Comment: Antes que se cargue el formulario no, salvo que se cargue en otro lado que no sea el formulario y despues se lo pases. Si no, porque no usar el evento load del formulario?

Comment: Tene en cuenta que en el constructor, el formulario ya esta cargado ;)

Comment: Vale, no se si reescribirlo de 0, ya que con el load, al hacer llamadas await tengo que ponerlo async y lo que hace es cargarme el formulario completamente vacío, eso ya lo había probado.

Comment: no te sirve mostrar un gif o progress indicando que esta cargando ? lo planteo porque en web se usa mucho, en winform al usar el async\await podrias implemntarlo ya que no frenaria su visualizacion

Comment: Mostraría lo que quisiera siempre y cuando consiguiese que cargase antes de visualizar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No se si esta del todo bien implementado pero creo puede dar una idea

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    Frmprogress frmProgress = null;

    public FormAreaPersonal()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, true);
        InitializeComponent();
        DoubleBuffered = true;

        frmProgress = new Frmprogress();
        frmProgress.Show();
    }

    public void Form1_Load(...)
    {
        this.Hide();

        sacarCurso();
        if (usuario.Equals("invitado") || curso == 0)
        {
            cargarModelo();
        }
        else
        {
            loadAsync();
            cargaGraficas(curso);
        }

        frmProgress.Close();
        this.Show();
    }


    private async void loadAsync()
    {
        Task<int> cursoTask = met.sacarCurso(usuario);
        Task<int> userTask = met.sacarUsuario(usuario);
        Task<List<string>> asignaturasTask = met.sacarAsignaturas(curso, usuario);

        await Task.WhenAll(cursoTask, userTask, asignaturasTask);

        curso = await cursoTask;
        user = await userTask;
        nombresAsignaturas = await asignaturasTask;
    }

}
```

Durante la carga ocultas el form y muestras otro que contenga un `ProgressBar` con la opcion de `Marquee` para que indique trabajo pero no un progreso real, ya que no sabras cuanto va a demorar

Entonces esperas que las operaciones `async` termine para ocultar el form del progress y mostrar con los datos cargados

Esto recuerdo que con el `BackGroundWorker` es simple porque hay un evento `Completed` pero con `async\await` no estos del todo seguro como esperar al finalizacion

Comment: Puede servirme, gracias